How does the dependencies in kotlin multiplatform work?
I recently started new project based on kotlin multiplatform template provided by jetbrains and it turned out that I was not happy that it don't feature version for the terminal right of the box. So I tried to add terminal module next to server and composeApp. The module works but as of it stands now it is made for java environment and wanting to change that turned out to be harder than I anticipated.
Actual question
How to modify project to add jvm, Dmg, Msi and Deb targets to terminal module. For all my tries i managed to add them by adding multiplatform plugin to my terminal build.gradle.kts but then my dependencies didn't showed up in the project and I am using shared code so that approach proved difficult.
build.gradle.kts (:terminal)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    application
}

group = "pl.game.terminal"
version = "unspecified"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(projects.shared)
    testImplementation(libs.kotlin.test.junit)
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    mingwX64 {
        binaries { 
            executable()
        }
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = "pl.game.terminal.MainKt"
}

Whole project is available here so you can check it out yourself. This link provides github access to the commit where there is working java target and multiplatform is not implemented.
After changes
I added changes mentioned in answer provided by Kevin in this Commit. The problem I'm facing right now is that my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) is reporting lack of classes from base Kotlin, I'm getting Unresolved reference: readLine or Unresolved reference: Thread while I can clearly compile my terminal module to exe and jar executables while using readln instead and I confirmed they both work fine. Is this some kind of bug or maybe my default JDK configuration provide needed dependencies while I'm using it to compile?

You should include a branch where you've added the native targets. If you only added them to terminal, then that's your problem. Your dependencies also need to have the platform targets. However, don't add the binaries section.
So for the case above, the shared config would look something like this:
kotlin {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalWasmDsl::class)
    wasmJs {
    // Wasm stuff
    }

    androidTarget {
    // Yada yada
    }
    
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    iosSimulatorArm64()
    
    jvm()

    mingwX64() // <- You need this
    
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            // put your Multiplatform dependencies here
        }
    }
}


I looks like I still can't seem to generate binary like that, maybe I don't understand what I am doing, are you able to provide any helpful links to this answer? I already read through Kotlin Multiplatform

Update your sample with the config you think should work.

I updated the question, look at the new chapter, thanks
